# multiple configurations file in webpack for angular

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm not sure this is a Webpack question or an Angular one, but I have an Angular app which is using webpack with a very similar setup to the one in the [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) site.

So I have my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = require('./config/webpack.dev.js');
```

which is used by default when I execute my task

```
"start-webpack": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress"
```

but I have a few app parameters that I need to setup when running the application, like a couple API urls and some other stuff. So I have a folder /env with a few files dev1.ts, dev2.ts like this:

```
export = {
  API: 'http://xxxx',
  BASE_URL: 'http://xxxx',
};
```

and I'd like to be able to access this information once the application is started. So ideally I'd start the application with something like this:

```
"start-webpack": "webpack-dev-server --config dev1 --inline --progress"
```

and then in my Angular app I'd retrieve API, BASE_URL somehow. 
I'm a bit lost because I don´t even know if this is feasible.

Can anyone give me a hint on where to look?

Thanks

Comment: You are probably looking for [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) for globals and [this](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/) for having different environments.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not sure, this way I would need to have a different webpack config for each setup; in this case, I have 2 development configurations and 2 production configurations but I don´t want to have 4 different webpack configuration files

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my issue; thanks to @Ivan for the hint.

Finally this my package.json scripts section:

```
"start1": "webpack-dev-server --env.config=dev1 --inline --progress",
"start2": "webpack-dev-server --env.config=dev2 --inline --progress",
```

and so in my webpack.web.js I have this:

```
const envConfig = {
  dev1: {
    API: xxxx
  },
  dev2: {
    API: yyyy
  }
}

module.exports = (env = {}) => {

  return webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    ...
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.CONFIG': JSON.stringify(envConfig[env.config])
      })
    ],
    ...
  });
}
```

and now I can access my configuration inside Angular just with process.env.CONFIG (it can be any other name, obviously).
In my case it makes sense to have dev1 and dev2 because I have some other urls and properties inside, but in case I wanted to expose a single property I could do this instead:

```
const envConfig = {
  dev1: xxxx,
  dev2: yyyy
}
```

Also, [this link](https://blog.flennik.com/the-fine-art-of-the-webpack-2-config-dc4d19d7f172#.297u8iuz1) helped me to configure everything.

Hope it helps if someone needs something similar.